# What are the best resources to learn XML?

Tags: xml

I wish to learn XML so I can use it with ASP.NET. Can anyone please provide me the URL of an online resource (or, in the worst case, the book name) which has good content about XML?  If it contains information about XSLT/XSL, that would be even better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The O'Reilly website **http://www.xml.com/** is a good place to start. The home page has a sidebar with links like:

- What is XML?
- What is XSLT?
- What is XSL-FO?
- What is XLink?
- What is XML Schema?
- What is XQuery?

However this is not a beginners only site, it features regular articles from many good practitioners on how to get the most out of XML.

**http://www.w3schools.com/xml/** is another good site with great introductory and intermediate level content.

Answer (score 5):

certainly not bad:

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/

Answer (score 2):

This book is available free online: [Sams Teach Yourself XML in 21 Days](http://www.informit.com/library/library.aspx?b=STY_XML_21days)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to understand XML, read the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/).

It is not the easiest read, but it is the most authoritative.